# Unable to fetch multiple rows from MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I wanna **fetch all the rows with email ID "Chaitanya.pro@live.com"** from a MySQL Database using PDO. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php 
$config= array(
    'DB_USERNAME' => 'root',
    'DB_PASSWORD' => 'mihir111');

try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=social', $config['DB_USERNAME'],   $config['DB_PASSWORD']);

    $staement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM places_visited WHERE email = :email');

    $staement->execute( array( 'email' => 'chaitanya.pro@live.com' ) );
    $results = $staement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($results);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
        // echo 'ERROR'.$e->getMessage();
        return false;
}

?>
```

I connected database using **PDO function** then i used the **prepared statements** to execute the **MySQL query**.

But when i try to var_dump those rows **It returns only one row.** I've added 4 rows with email = chaitanya.pro@live.com. But still it returns only one row.

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["email"]=>
  string(22) "chaitanya.pro@live.com"
  ["place_name"]=>
  string(7) "Dominos"
  ["venue_name"]=>
  string(11) "Kamla Nagar"
}
```

I'm noob at PHP please help me out. Thanks

Comment: A single call to `->fetch` only returns one row. The manual also shows some loop examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php), `fetch` only fetches one row. 
Try calling `fetch` successively or use [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Iterative example:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```